# Is it safe to checkin the changes done to the application while changing Visual Studio versions

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am working on ASP.NET 2.0 application. Initially while opening the application in VS 2010, it has given prompt message something like application is developed in VS2005 and need to make changes in order to open in VS2010.

Now when I see the differences the wizard has done, it is mostly to the *.sln, *.csproj, *.designer.cs. So, is it safe to check-in these changes given all developers are now using VS2010. Does it only effect only visual studio and does it break any existing functionality.

Previous **.csproj file**

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Modified **.csproj file**

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<FileUpgradeFlags>
</FileUpgradeFlags>
<OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion>
<UpgradeBackupLocation />
```

Previous ***.designer.cs.**

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "9.0.0.0")]
```

Modified ***.designer.cs.**

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: The benefit of using the source control system is you can roll it back if it doesn't work.  It won't affect the generated code, those changes are for the VS version only.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason for the warning is that the post-conversion project cannot be opened in VS 2005 (or 2008 for that matter). If the rest of your shop is on 2010, and the post-conversion project builds successfully for you, it won't be a problem for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

If after the upgrade the project builds and all developers are using 2010 then I would go ahead and commit.